# No redirection by apache when using htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have just recently setup a new development environment and ever since I have been unable to access any page on my site outwith the homepage.

For instance, if I go to: www.herpandderp.com/contact_us it throws a 404 error.

There is no directory called /contact_us and I have code in my index.php that handles the URL as a parameter, takes it in and will include/require the appropriate code as required.

This is the entry in my root .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ /index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

If I do a phpinfo, I get the following under apache2handler (so I know mod_rewrite is installed):

> Loaded Modules core prefork http_core mod_so mod_auth_basic
>   mod_auth_digest mod_authn_file mod_authn_alias mod_authn_anon
>   mod_authn_dbm mod_authn_default mod_authz_host mod_authz_user
>   mod_authz_owner mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_dbm mod_authz_default
>   mod_log_config mod_logio mod_env mod_mime_magic mod_expires
>   mod_deflate mod_headers mod_usertrack mod_setenvif mod_mime mod_status
>   mod_autoindex mod_info mod_vhost_alias mod_negotiation mod_dir
>   mod_actions mod_speling mod_userdir mod_alias **mod_rewrite**
>   mod_cache mod_disk_cache mod_file_cache mod_mem_cache mod_perl
>   mod_php5 mod_ssl

Is there any reason why, if I go to /contact_us that I don't go through index.php? I've got a die on line 1 of the script and it's not hitting it. However, it *does* work when I do www.herpandderp.com/?url=contact.

I feel this is an apache configuration issue, as the code runs on other environments fine.

Comment: Hazarding a guess: do you have a line `RewriteEngine On` before that line in `.htaccess`?

Comment: I've just tried it with a mod_php5 and a mod_suphp config, and it works fine (with `RewriteEngine On`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that in your httpd.conf, that the site in question has AllowOverride all set, other wise the rewrite won't be able to over ride the default settings for that site.

Answer (score 0):

In your `.htaccess` add in the first line:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Is it working?